# How do we know the relationship between the Royal Baby and these celebrity children?

Tags: relationship-analysis

The findmypast.com blog recently posted an article which shares [how the Royal Baby is related to the children of some celebrities](http://blog.findmypast.com/2013/07/06/royal-baby-related-to-other-celebrity-kids/). This includes:

- Children of Jennifer Garner and Ben Affleck
- Daughter of Uma Thurman and Arpad Busson
- Daughters of Maggie Gyllenhaal and Peter Sarsgaard
- Son of Hilary Duff and Mike Comrie
- Daughter of Beyoncé Knowles and Jay-Z
- Children of Brad Pitt and Angelina Jolie
- Children of Celine Dion and Rene Angelil

How were they able to determine the exact relationship to so many celebrities? Is the ancestry of most celebrities well known? Is there a program which can automatically calculate how my children are related to celebrities? If not, how can I calculate this on my own?

Comment: This question seems to come close to celebrity genealogy. I think the simple answer (unless you have reason to believe otherwise) is that someone just did the research like (to some extent) you or I would.

Answer (score 1):

Television programs such as [WDYTYA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Do_You_Think_You_Are%3F_%28UK_TV_series%29) select high-profile subjects who might be described by some as celebrities. In the course of their investigations into the history of that person, they (often) refer to a link to other "famous" people such as US presidents or UK royalty.

I believe that the program that involved Maggie Gyllenhall made a claim of a link to Edward III that would be sufficient to calculate a cousin claim of the type you describe. I imagine that there is sufficient information in many gossip magazines regarding other people in your list.

The quality of the supporting evidence is another matter entirely.